# How can I acces css root variables on change in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have an object called animationInfo and I get the variable circleDuration inside this object from :root.
I get this :root variable from a different class with a method called getCircleDurationTime().
I write this value into the input. When I change this input, I send it to a method called setCircleDurationTime().
but after that, when I write the getCircleDurationTime() function in the template, I see that the data does not change. How can I capture when the data here changes?

and my html code

```
<template>
        <div class="btnContainer">
          <div>
            {{ circleDuration }}
            <div>Circle Duration Time</div>
            <el-input-number v-model="circleDuration " :min="1" @change="setCircleDurationTime" />
          </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

js code

```
getCircleDurationTime = function () {
        return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--variable');
};

setCircleDurationTime = function (_duration) {
        return this.root.style.setProperty('--variable);
};
```

```
const circleDuration = getCircleDurationTime()
```

I can't get the new parameter changed when calling getCircleDurationTime() here.
How can I get new value in here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS : How can I access and change Css root variables from vue component to toggle CSS Variables Site Theming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802008/vue-js-how-can-i-access-and-change-css-root-variables-from-vue-component-to-to)

Comment: Use vueuse's useCssVar